# Why are my Terminal.app colors different from iTerm?

Tags: terminal, iterm, color

I have set the ANSI colors of both terminals to be the same (see 1st screenshot), but the colors for Terminal.app are really bright, and almost unreadable, and not like the colors I set at all.

It's not just the prompt as well. Even with Vim the colors are different.

EDIT: It's like in Terminal.app, something is overriding colors. B

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's a completely different program? Do not expect every application to use all color-schemes exact the same way.

Comment: Umm, why would I not assume that?

Answer (score 1):

There has been some discussion on the web about iTerm2's color accuracy being off,

- https://github.com/altercation/solarized/issues/257
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278267/incorrect-colors-with-vim-in-iterm2-using-solarized

Including a bug report on iTerm2 issue tracker, https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/3989.

Sounds like it might just be a iTerm2 issue.

Answer (score -1):

I think iTerm uses its own configuration file for holding what color values are applied to where.

As for Terminal it relies on the Bash profile configuration file. It is usually found in /User/USERNAME/.bash_config.

Here is an example of mine.

[image]

For a bash ls colors generator as seen on line three in this image visit here: http://geoff.greer.fm/lscolors/

Comment: I don't have a .bash_config, and both screenshots use the same .bash_profile. I tried copying your LSCOLORS expecting it to at least change the `ls` colors, but they're the same.

Comment: In OS X, `.bash_profile` is used in lieu of the traditional Linux `.bash_config` and by default, it does not exit, the user has to create it.

Comment: Your `bash` config certainly does not affect what Terminal.app thinks the colors are.  It **may** affect the appearance of colors `bash` uses for various things.

Comment: Dunno man, it worked for me 8 years ago. Haven't been on macOS in years lol